# Removing a non empty folder in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

How to remove a non-empty folder in Qt.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Recursively delete the contents of the directory first. [Here is a blog post with sample code for doing just that.](http://john.nachtimwald.com/2010/06/08/qt-remove-directory-and-its-contents/) I've included the relevant code snippet.

```
bool removeDir(const QString & dirName)
{
    bool result = true;
    QDir dir(dirName);

    if (dir.exists()) {
        Q_FOREACH(QFileInfo info, dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::System | QDir::Hidden  | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files, QDir::DirsFirst)) {
            if (info.isDir()) {
                result = removeDir(info.absoluteFilePath());
            }
            else {
                result = QFile::remove(info.absoluteFilePath());
            }

            if (!result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        result = QDir().rmdir(dirName);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Edit**: The above answer was for Qt 4. If you are using Qt 5, then this functionality is built into QDir with the [QDir::removeRecursively()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#removeRecursively) method .

Comment: Seems like will not work for relative paths. removeDir("docs") will check if "docs/docs" exists in the first if. The same problem is in dir.rmdir line. Am I right ?

Comment: @cybevnm: Yes, you are right. I changed the snippet to use the overloaded  `exists()` method without parameters. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#exists-2

Comment: The "result = dir.rmdir(dirName)" line has the same defect I believe. I have used QDir().rmdir(dirName) to fix it.

Answer (score 54):

If you're using Qt 5, there is [QDir::removeRecursively()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#removeRecursively).