# Deleting a folder and all its contents with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

How to delete a folder and all its contents with `Qt`?

I tried using:

```
QFile::remove();
```

but it seems like it deletes only one file a time.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050977/removing-a-non-empty-folder-in-qt

Comment: @InnocentBystander beat you by 25 seconds :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing a non empty folder in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050977/removing-a-non-empty-folder-in-qt)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For Qt5 and above there is [`QDir::removeRecursively`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#removeRecursively):

```
QDir dir("C:\\Path\\To\\Folder\\Here");
dir.removeRecursively();
```

For Qt4 or lower you can use a recursive function that deletes every file:

```
bool removeDir(const QString & dirName)
{
    bool result = true;
    QDir dir(dirName);

    if (dir.exists(dirName)) {
        Q_FOREACH(QFileInfo info, dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::System | QDir::Hidden  | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files, QDir::DirsFirst)) {
            if (info.isDir()) {
                result = removeDir(info.absoluteFilePath());
            } else {
                result = QFile::remove(info.absoluteFilePath());
            }

            if (!result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        result = dir.rmdir(dirName);
    }
    return result;
}
```

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050977/removing-a-non-empty-folder-in-qt).

Comment: I deleted the whole directory contains about 700 files source code, fortunately I committed to svn one day before. The `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` is very important, elsewhere it jumps one height level and then it will delete everything there