# Removing Directory in Qt

Tags: qt, directory, delete-file

I want to remove folder:

```
QDir dir1;
dir.remove("TEST");
```

Failed, because there is a subfolder:

```
TEST
  └A
   └B
```

Also tried another way:

```
QProcess  pProcess = new QProcess;
QString total;
total="TEST";
list1<<"-r"+total;
pProcess->execute("rm",list1);
```

This time it fails with:

```
rm: Inappropriate options -- 'L'
```

How can I delete the directory with sub-directories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing a non empty folder in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050977/removing-a-non-empty-folder-in-qt)

Comment: @demonplus thanks , but Deletion is not. my Qt ver 4.8

Comment: Maybe you should try list1 << "-r"  << total;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool removeDirRecursively(const QString& dirPath)
{
    QDir dir(dirPath);
    bool r = dir.removeRecursively();
    qDebug() << "The directory remove operation " <<
         (r ? "finished successfully" : "failed");
}
```